# .htaccess help - hide .php and add ?lang=

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I can hide the .php extension in the URL with my .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

So an url like this: **url.com/prices.php**

currently looks like: **url.com/prices**

That's great, but i would like to look like this: **url.com/en/prices**

instead of this: **url.com/prices?lang=en**

I tried for an hour, searched for any types of the internet, i can do these separate, but not together. Thanks for any help :)

UPDATE: also, it would be great, that if they opens the index page (http://url.com) it would be immediately changed in the url to: http://url.com/en  (or to the other languages of course, based on their browser language)

UPDATE2: At the moment my solution for languages: i set a cookie for the user, and use `$language=$_COOKIE["language"];` They can choose the language in the menu

Comment: For the last, dind about  `%{HTTP:Accept-Language}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteRule  ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /prices.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

This should get you sorted

Comment: Not working with: `RewriteRule  ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]`

I get an 404 error when opening url.com/en or url.com/en/page